# Telling a Cloud Run Instance to Terminate

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-run

I'm using a Cloud Run to run my deployment test suite. It takes about 3 minutes to run the suite and my instance timeout is set to 5 minutes.

I've set up a Cloud Run project that will accept an http request (from my CI provider) triggering the tests to run, and then report back pass/fail.

Even though the containers are set to only handle 1 concurrent request they are accepting a second request after the first test run completes. As the first run took up 3 of the available 5 minutes, the Second request times-out at 2 minutes.

So, does anyone know of a way to either self terminate a given instance (preferably from within) or to set the total number of requests an instance will accept before closing itself?

Thank you very much for reading my question. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

You don't have instance timeout in Cloud Run. The timeout is on the request processing. You set the maximum duration time to process a request (up to 3600 seconds). So, in your case, you haven't this timeout issue, or I didn't understand your configuration and current issue.

The other part of your question is "how to stop an instance". Simply exit it! According to your language the method are different. In python for example `exit(0)`.

Comment: I'm using node, and process.exit(0) did the trick for me. thank you! Regarding the timeout issue, my mistake. It is indeed per request, it looks like the issue was due to the first request caching some of the output, which caused the second to fail. By exiting the process, I get a clean container for the second request.